# Speeding Up a User Defined Function

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have user defined function that is tied to 2 other user defined functions and when I update the cell it can take several minutes (5-10) as the file has up to 400k cells, and it is is running through 2 other custom functions to create a date format we use at my work.  It seems to be looping through them and takes a long time.

Here are the custom functions:

```
Function FL_YR_PDxWK(MY_DATE)
    FL_YR_PDxWK = FL_YEAR(MY_DATE) & "_" & Right("00" & FL_PERIOD(MY_DATE), 
2) & "x" & FL_WEEK(MY_DATE)
End Function
```

Which looks at these 2:

```
Function FL_PERIOD(MY_DATE)

If DatePart("yyyy", MY_DATE + (7 - Weekday(MY_DATE))) = DatePart("yyyy", 
MY_DATE) Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) / 
4), 1) = 14 Then
            FL_PERIOD = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) / 4), 1) - 1
       Else
            FL_PERIOD = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) / 4), 1)
End If
Else
    FL_PERIOD = 1
End If
End Function
```

AND

```
Function FL_WEEK(MY_DATE)

If DatePart("yyyy", MY_DATE + (7 - Weekday(MY_DATE))) = DatePart("yyyy", 
MY_DATE) Then
        If DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) Mod 4 = 0 Then
            FL_WEEK = 4
        Else
            If DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) = 53 Then
                FL_WEEK = 5
            Else
                FL_WEEK = DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) Mod 4
            End If
        End If
    Else
        FL_WEEK = 1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Can you please give a little explanation as to what each function is meant to accomplish?

Comment: You answered your own question : `it is is running through 2 other custom functions`...  make them more efficient by compressing into one, and making sure any given value only needs to be calculated once (if needed repeatedly, use variable or arrays instead of functions.)

Comment: ...and also, as @JosephSerido said, your functions need ***comments*** and additional explanation, and also some sample data would be helpful and a bit of background about what you're trying to do.  (otherwise it's like saying, "My house fell down, what's wrong with this hammer?")  See [mcve].

Comment: Also, I highly recommend specifying `Option Explicit` in your module, specifying if your function is `public` or `private`, always state if you intend to use `ByRef` or `ByVal`, and definitely specify what type the function is returning `public MyFunc(ByRef myString) As Boolean`

Comment: Use result value of  function not function itself. And use variant  array to getting  result.

Comment: It's the nature of UDFs to be slow in large quantities, as the same logic is repeated over and over for each cell. I would "speed it up" by replacing with a macro having a loop and multiple cells output.

Comment: Also, we're missing the `FL_YEAR` function in your code snippets

Answer (score 0):

You call `.Ceiling(...` twice in FL_PERIOD with the same parameters and you make the same calculation twice. Replace

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) / 4), 1) = 14 Then
```

with

```
Dim iWeek as Long
Dim iRetVal as Long
iWeek = If Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((DatePart("ww", MY_DATE) / 4), 1)
If iWeek = 14 Then
      iRetVal = iWeek - 1
      ...
FL_PERIOD = iRetVal
```

You can apply the same concept on FL_WEEK where you call `If DatePart("ww", MY_DATE)` twice.

An additional option to speed up your code is to use correct and specific types. The current version performs many type conversion as `Function FL_YR_PDxWK(MY_DATE)` produces a string while the other functions produce integers. What actually happens is VBA uses `Variants` and tries to convert them to the desired form. What you should do is to specify the types correctly like this:

```
Function FL_PERIOD(MY_DATE as Date) as String     ' will return string
...
```

As a bonus, you can make formatting within the function to return the desired 2 digit format like this:

```
FL_PERIOD = Format (iRetVal, "00")
End Function
```

so you can omit the `Right` function call in `FL_YR_PDxWK`.

Considering the vast amount of calculation, I would reccommend another trick to save additional seconds by reducing the number of system calls: as you can be sure that iRetVal is between 1 and 53, you can use this instead of `Format`

```
If iRetval < 10 Then
   FL_PERIOD = "0" & CStr(iRetVal)
Else
   FL_PERIOD = CStr(iRetVal)
Endif
```